# What is a suitable index to express similarity in two observations of the same set of variables containing ratios?

Tags: correlation, adjacency-matrix, data-structure

Is there an index that would express *any* kind of similarity between the values in the same variable sets of **two** observations, for example the distribution of energy-sources of two countries.

I work with a panel data of the energy mix of countries where each observation of a country has a set of variables for energy-sources expressed as shares of all energy consumed by origin. The variables are the same across panels and could for example be `{coal, oil, nuclear, wind, hydro, other}` with no missing data and `{0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1}` as an example observation.

I wish to compare the similarity of the energy-mix of each country-pair expressed as a single measure, for example between 0 and 1.

Given whatever definition of *similarity* you find appropriate, how should I reason to compute a **pair-wise** similarity index in which two countries with a similar energy mix will score highly.

Comment: Why don't you just use the [Sample Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#Pearson's_product-moment_coefficient)? I feel like it's a bad idea to restrict yourself to only positive relationships, as two countries could be negatively correlated and that might be interesting information as well.

Comment: Certainly the scale of the measure is un-important. A correlation I don't understand how to apply in this case. It could be read as negative, absent, or positive, but the measure I'm looking for should be read on a scale from not similar to similar: `{.1, .2, .3, .4}` and `{.1, .2, .3, .4}` should max out the measure `{.1, .2, .3, .4}` and `{.11, .19, .3, .4}` should be an almost maximum while `{0, 0, .5, .5}` and `{.5, .5, 0, 0}` should compute the minimum of similarity and `{.2, .2, .3, .3}` and `{.1, .3, .1, .5}` a similarity somewhere in the middle of the scale.

Comment: I think you could probably just use $\frac{(1+\rho_{ij})}{2}$, where $\rho_{ij}$ is the sample correlation between countries $i$ and $j$. This would give you $0$ if the countries had a negative correlation, and 1 if they were positively correlated. Your vectors are strictly positive, so I think all projections of one vector onto another will be positive, meaning the correlations are all positive anyway. In this situation you wouldn't need to add the $1$ term, and could just use $\rho_{ij}$ as the sample correlation for your similarity contained in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Duly noted. I'm was looking in to a kind of jaccard similarity but will compare and evaluate. Many thanks.